# Admin-on-Rest How to create a custom Show component to add Filter

Tags: admin-on-rest

I would like to create a custom `Show` component that can utilize the `Filter` component that the `List` component uses. I honestly don't know where to begin on this one. Can someone point me in the right direction?

This is how it is used in `List`:

```
export const LogList = (props) => (
    <List {...props} perPage={100} title="Logs and Reports" filters={< FileFilter/>}>
```

I would like to be able to use it in `Show` like so:

```
export const archivedShow = ({ ...props }) => (
        <Show title="Log" {...props} filters={<LogFilter/>} >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a custom connected component. Then you can do as you wish.

You can provide actions to the show component just like any other comp.
https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Show.html#actions

You can use this action to populate a field in your State (probably using a custom reducer)

Your Component can then be connected to the redux state.

something like below

```
class connectedReferenceInput extends Component {
  render() {
    <ReferenceInput source={this.props.source} >
      <somecomp>
    </ReferenceInput>
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
  return {
    source: state.admin.somefield.source
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  crudGetList: crudGetListAction
})(ClientInput)
```

There are also docs for writing a reducer in AOR docs.

**MORE DETAILS**: 
1) somecomp is any component that you need as child of the referenceInput
2) somefield is any field that you set up to pass data between the connected filter component and the connectedReferenceInput.

Breakup of what you are doing essentially.

1) create a connected component that you will make a child of filter. This connected component shoots a redux 'Action' that changes some part of your state by a 'reducer'

Docs for both writing an action and a reducer are available in aor docs.

2) create a connectedReferenceInput (like above) this receives (through mapStateToProps) the state changes that your connectedFilterComp makes. Using this you can create a variable filter for referenceInput and display your variable data.

You are basically using redux to pass data between the filter and your component.

Comment: Sorry I am new to redux, for `<somecomp>` that would be Filter in this case? Also for source: `state.admin.somefield.source` what is `somefield`? I am a little confused what that is supposed to be. @kunal pareek

Comment: somefield is a just that: an arbitrary field you set up with a reducer and an action in your state. 
somecomp would be any child of referenceInput that you choose/need

AOR uses redux to manage state so kinda would be good for you to look into it. A short gist of everything is -  Redux is the state storage, you can store all the state info there instead of passing state as props through different components. mapStateToProps takes some small slice of the state and essentially turns it into props that your connected component receives.

Comment: Editing answer above for greater clarity